# I can't get a value with key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keras

I'm using 'Matchzoo' text retrieval library which is based on keras. I want to use the trained result, but it's dictionary and I can't get the value with shown keys.

After training the model,

```
>>> history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=1, callbacks=[evaluate], workers=5, use_multiprocessing=False)
Epoch 1/1
17/17 [==============================] - 1s 84ms/step - loss: 1.0864
Validation: normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0): 0.03594548089735716 - normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@5(0.0): 0.04159539212363794 - mean_average_precision(0.0): 0.044539607256746286
```

The result is in `history.history` dictionary.

```
>>> history.history
{'loss': [1.2375952883301495],
 mean_average_precision(0.0): [0.02962496886265635],
 normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0): [0.018740542440172665],
 normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@5(0.0): [0.027987588892336258]}
```

There are 4 keys, I can see them when I check the dict's keys.

```
>>> history.history.keys()
dict_keys(['loss', normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0), normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@5(0.0), mean_average_precision(0.0)])
```

But when I try to use them, I can't.

```
>>> history.history[normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-9526d848c6d7> in <module>()
----> 1 history.history[normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0)]

NameError: name 'normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain' is not defined
```

What I can't understand is that I can use some keys, but not all.

```
>>> history.history['loss']
[1.0869888107353283]
>>> history.history[mean_average_precision(0.0)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-985db34a9846> in <module>()
----> 1 history.history[mean_average_precision(0.0)]

NameError: name 'mean_average_precision' is not defined
```

I wondered if it's because the keys were not string, but it didn't work either.

```
>>> history.history['mean_average_precision(0.0)']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-985db34a9846> in <module>()
----> 1 history.history[mean_average_precision(0.0)]

NameError: name 'mean_average_precision' is not defined
```

Can someone tell me why and how I can solve this problem? Is there anything I should check?

Comment: looks like they are not strings.. try this: `history.history[list(history.history.keys())[2]]`.
Does that work?

Comment: @Prateek wow it worked.....thank you so much. I spent last few days because of this.

Comment: @Prateek Can you tell me why this worked but didn't work when I try to get the value with keys? I asked this question because what I really wanted was to use that key as an argument value of other functions. Your answer worked for that too, but I just know the reason why.

Comment: Glad that worked. Added that as an answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it could be because they are not strings. If you are sure that's the order they are coming in, try indexing through the dictionary using the keys as shown below..

```
history.history[list(history.history.keys())[2]]
```

and

```
history.history[list(history.history.keys())[3]]
```

etc..

By doing this, we avoid guessing the data type of the key by letting the computer retrieve the object.

Most possibly, `normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain@3(0.0)`, etc. are not strings. They might be objects of a different type. If you want to check what exactly it is, you can try this

```
type(list(history.history.keys())[2])
```

This will show str for 'loss' as it is a string and something else for the others. If you try that, please comment on what type it is in the comment.

Comment: I checked the type and found that it's a class. (For example the result was `matchzoo.metrics.normalized_discounted_cumulative_gain.NormalizedDiscountedCumulativeGain`). It seems that it's not working well as an argument value of another function though.....but your answer was very helpful. Thank you again :)